# Формирование дерева из таблицы EF Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, дерево, entity-framework-core

Есть сущность, которая хранится в SQLite:

```
public class PositionRelation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentPositionId { get; set; }
    public Position ParentPosition { get; set; }

    public Guid ChildPositionId { get; set; }
    public Position ChildPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Её суть сделать структуру должностей такую, что у каждой должности есть N количество поддолжностей, с любой вложенностью, например:

```
                  Должность 1
                  /         \
            Должность 2      Должность 3
            /   \
Должность 2.2   Должность 2.3
```

Я бы хотел одним запросом в EFCore подгрузить "вложенные" связи чтобы из полученной коллекции сделать дерево. Как это можно сделать? Или стоит переделать модель? На ум приходит только лишь рекурсия. Так же были мысли добавить свойство `string Path`, который будет хранить формат `node1/node2/node3` чтобы потом пройтись `Path.Contains(position.Id)`

Comment: Как много у вас должностей в БД? Может, проще их все выгрузить в память и там с ними уже делать, что хочется?

Comment: если всё таки надо запросом, то я не слышал о рекурсивном linq запросе (может кто поопытней подскажет), ну или [рекурсинвный SQL](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server) может помочь, если SQLite его поддерживает.

Comment: @tym32167 да, можно в память всё выгрузить

Comment: ну тогда совсем просто, выгрузить все в память и там построить дерево. Непонятно только зачем вам отдельная таблица для связей, нельзя просто в таблицу Position добавить Parent? Судя по структуре у вас не ожидается более 1 парента на должность.

Comment: также вот тут `public Guid? ParentPositionId { get; set; }` гуид не должен допускать null. Если вы про топ парентов, то для них просто не будет записей в `PositionRelation` где они в роли чилда.

Comment: @tym32167 парент для должности только 1 может быть, чайлдов много. да, nullable parentId убрать стоит

Comment: я бы вообще тогда всю таблицу убрал `PositionRelation` и добавил бы в `Position` таблицу парента - тогда вам не придется валидировать связи, только убедиться, что в таблице нет циклов

Comment: @tym32167 да, так я и сделал. в position parentId добавил и сделал дерево, спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Такой способ хранения иерархий называется "список смежности" - adjacency list. Для работы с ним нужны рекурсивные запросы в CTE. Следовательно, нужен сырой SQL. Либо единственная linq-подобная ORM, которая умеет в CTE: [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html). Впрочем, есть расширение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). Оно есть в списке [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо огромное за ссылки